# Displaying database record on a label in VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have this problem that when I put id no. in the textbox1 and click the button1 the record successfully shows, but when I change the id no. in the textbox1 and click button1 again the error says

> ArgumentException was unhandled
>
> This causes two bindings in the collection to bind to the same property. Parameter name: binding

I really don't understand the meaning of this, by the way still new and getting used to vb.net

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form16

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim thisConnection As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=root;database=db")
        Dim DataSet1 As New DataSet


        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM voter where vid='" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(sql, thisConnection)

        da.Fill(DataSet1, "db")
        Label2.DataBindings.Add("text", DataSet1, "db.fname")
        Label10.DataBindings.Add("text", DataSet1, "db.mi")
        Label11.DataBindings.Add("text", DataSet1, "db.lname")
        Label12.DataBindings.Add("text", DataSet1, "db.yr")
        Label13.DataBindings.Add("text", DataSet1, "db.sec")
        Label14.DataBindings.Add("text", DataSet1, "db.vstatus")

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't *clear* the `DataBindings` collection *before* rebinding, this error will be thrown because a control can only have *one* binding to a specified property.

For instance, `Label2` can only have one binding to the property `Text`. But when you're clicking the button for the second time the binding added in the first click is still in the collection.

First click:

```vb
Label2.DataBindings.Add("Text", DataSet1, "db.fname")
```

Second click:

```vb
'Will throw an error because there's already a binding to property `Text`:
Label2.DataBindings.Add("Text", DataSet1, "db.fname")
```

Before you add a new binding, be sure the binding doesn't already exists.

```vb
'Always do a reversed loop when removing items from a collection.
For index As Integer = (Label2.DataBindings.Count - 1) To 0 Step -1
    If (Label2.DataBindings.Item(index).PropertyName = "Text") Then
        'Ops, a binding to the property `Text` already exists.
        'Remove this and we'll be fine.
        Label2.DataBindings.RemoveAt(index)
    End If
Next

'We can now safely add a new binding to the `Text` property.
Label2.DataBindings.Add("Text", DataSet1, "db.fname")
```

A more simpler way is to just clear the collection.

```
Label2.DataBindings.Clear()
Label2.DataBindings.Add("Text", DataSet1, "db.fname")
```